# How to auto create parent packages by groupId and artifactId in pom xml

Tags: maven, package

when creating maven projects, do a lot rework to create specified parent package.
such as:
when created maven project with groupId com.test and artifactId jpa-demo,
later only thing to create packages: com.test.jpa.demo in src/main/java.

so how to auto create these pacs?

mm. didn't find useful plugin in IntelliJ Idea.

anyone know a good idea? tks.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to use is Maven Archetypes like this:

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

in interactive mode.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html